# Decoding .mkv (Matroska) video formats

Tags: c#, media, mkv, matroska

I have a media player that I made using c# and I wanted to decode mkv formats, but I can't find any good info about the codec or how to encode/decode mkv files. How can I decode matroska (mkv) video format?

Comment: By the way sorry if its already some question/answers on the internet on this subject but i did not find anything useful i hope you understand. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FFMPEG, VLC, DirectX (the most difficult, but probably most efficient way), and Gstreamer (my recommendation) all have .NET bindings. Take your pick.

[Here](http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/gst-plugins-good-plugins/html/gst-plugins-good-plugins-matroskamux.html) is a quick link for matroska in gstreamer to get you started:

Comment: Can i use Gstreamer with c# ? If yes, how ?

Comment: or just look into the sources for implementation, fortunately 3 of 4 are open-source.

Comment: Can you give me your email or something because i need more info about this

Comment: I dont know how to use Gstreamer and the same goes for the others too :(

Comment: @user2635745 To use gstreamer, start playing with the gstreamer command line tools, i.e. gst-launch. The pipeline you create there is easy to translate into code for virtually any language you want to use by reading the api documentation.

Comment: @user2635745 here is an example of using gstreamer in C#. It is an SO question I asked a few years ago. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10048757/gstreamer-link-a-bin-with-two-sinks-to-playbin2 Also note, you just need the playbin element in gstreamer. It will take care of the rest.

Comment: @Jonathan Henson I lost your email, send me your email to: r_tux97@yahoo.no please.